# $a,b \in Z$ and $p$ is prime. If $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm supposed to use Bezout's identity to prove this, but I don't really know how. Using purely what is given if $p$ is a prime then it's divisible by only 1 and itself so that means if $p\mid ab$ then $ab=px$, which means that $p=a$ or $p=b$. If $p=b$ then $(p,a)=1$ then $px+ay=1$. Then I get stuck.

Comment: Your second statement is false. $4 \cdot 3 = 12 = 2x$ but $2 \neq 3$ and $2 \neq 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p\mid ab\implies ab=pk$ for some integer $k$.
Now if $p\mid a$ then you are through.
If $p\not\mid a$ then we have by Bezout's identity $$px+ay=1$$
Now mulplying $b$ to both sides of the above equation we get $$pbx+aby=b \implies pbx+pky=b\implies p(bx+ky)=b$$.
As $b,x,k,y$ are all integers, $p\mid b$.

Comment: awesome! I think that px+by=1 is supposed to be px+ay=1 yes?

Comment: @Dylan Y, yes. Thanks for pointing out. Also $p\not\mid a\implies (p,a)=1$ as p is a prime. Therefore we can use Bezout's identity.